# How to specify conditions in dice game using Python?

Tags: python

I am a newbie a few weeks into learning code. I decided to build a craps game on my own using Python. I have a simple program written using the random module. It works great and generates the numbers like I wanted. However, I want my program to know the difference between rolling a 7,11,2,3,and 12 on the first roll and then on subsequent rolls. Right now each roll is completely new. I may not be articulating well exactly what I am looking to accomplish, but I hope there will be some feedback. my code is below. Feel free to critique other things you notice too. Maybe I am trying to get too complex on being 3 weeks into coding.

```
#dice roll
import random
while True:
    diceOutput=random.randint(1,6)
    diceOutput2=random.randint(1,6)
    diceRoll=input('Please type \'r\' to roll')

    if diceRoll== 'r':
        print(diceOutput)
        print(diceOutput2)

    else:
        print('Only type \'r\'')
```

Comment: You're right - you're not articulating what you want correctly. "[...] To know the difference between rolling a 7,11,2,3,and 12 on the first roll and then on subsequent rolls".
Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: What about appending each roll to a list, then testing the first element of the list for the values of interest?

Comment: In a craps game the "come out" roll or first roll of 2, 3, or 12 is said to have "crapped out' or lose. If the initial roll is a 7 or 11 you automatically win. If you roll any other number you are to keep rolling until you re-roll that same number or 7. Example, lets say you roll an 8. You would keep rolling trying to roll an 8. If you roll an 8 you win, if you roll a 7 before you roll an 8 you lose.

Comment: I think appending each roll to a list is a great idea. I will tinker around with that.

Comment: A little more abstract than you are probably ready for, but what you want to implement is a *state machine*.

Comment: You know how `if` works, you know how to assign a value to a variable. That's all you'll need for this game. Maybe a `break` to jump out of the loop once the game is won or lost. Some hints: The first roll is different, so it needs to be treated separately. Also, the result of the first roll needs to be compared to the subsequent rolls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way of saving the rolls in a list, with the possibility to check in later rolls, as well a sample check to see if the roll is a winner.

I think it may help to keep you going to complete what you're trying to achieve.

```py
#dice roll
import random

rolls = []

while True:
    diceRoll=input('Please type \'r\' to roll')

    if diceRoll != 'r':
        print('Only type \'r\'')
        continue

    diceOutput = random.randint(1,6)
    diceOutput2 = random.randint(1,6)

    print("dice 1:", diceOutput)
    print("dice 2:", diceOutput2)
    total_roll = diceOutput + diceOutput2

    if(total_roll == 7 or
       total_roll == 11):
        print('you win!')
        break

    rolls.append(total_roll)
```